# how to delete one column and row from jagged array in c#

Tags: c#

I have following jagged array of "dists"

```
int[][] dists = new int[][]
{
    new int[]{0,2,3,5,2},
    new int[]{2,0,1,3,5},
    new int[]{3,1,0,4,4},
    new int[]{5,3,4,0,2},
    new int[]{2,5,4,2,0}
};
```

now I want to create another jagged array named as `finalDists` when I remove the 3rd row and 3rd column from original array of `dists`. I mean I want finally have following jagged array:

```
int[][] finalDists = new int[][]
{
    new int[]{0,2,5,2},
    new int[]{2,0,3,5},
    new int[]{5,3,0,2},
    new int[]{2,5,2,0}
};
```

I am confused how to handle this issue, before all thanks for your help

Comment: Consider using existing solutions for mathematics and matrices. No need to reinvent the wheel, assuming that is a matrix with matrix logic applied to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int[][] finalDists = dists.Where((arr, i)=>i!=2) //skip row#3
                          .Select(arr=>arr.Where((item,i)=>i!=2) //skip col#3
                                          .ToArray())
                          .ToArray();
```

Comment: I had mistake, now your proposed solution works. :) Many thanks for your intimidate response.

Comment: I am new at Stackoverflow, I don't know how to accept and vote :)

Comment: Can you help for this probelm: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875959/how-to-keep-some-columns-and-rows-of-jagged-array-and-remove-unwanted-columns-an)  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not very optimized but:

```
public static T[] RemoveRow<T>(T[] array, int row)
{
    T[] array2 = new T[array.Length - 1];

    Array.Copy(array, 0, array2, 0, row);
    Array.Copy(array, row + 1, array2, row, array2.Length - row);

    return array2;
}

public static T[][] RemoveColumn<T>(T[][] array, int column)
{
    T[][] array2 = new T[array.Length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array2[i] = RemoveRow(array[i], column);
    }

    return array2;
}
```

and

```
int[][] dists = new int[][]
{
    new int[]{0,2,3,5,2},
    new int[]{2,0,1,3,5},
    new int[]{3,1,0,4,4},
    new int[]{5,3,4,0,2},
    new int[]{2,5,4,2,0}
};

int[][] dists2 = RemoveColumn(RemoveRow(dists, 2), 2);
```

Note that you want to remove the **third** row and the **third** column, but their index is **2**, because .NET arrays are 0-based indexed!