# How to keep some columns and rows of jagged array and remove unwanted columns and rows in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have following jagged array

```
int[][] dists1 = new int[][]
            {
               new int[]{0,2,3,5,2,4},
               new int[]{2,0,1,3,5,3},
               new int[]{3,1,0,4,4,3},
               new int[]{5,3,4,0,2,4},
               new int[]{2,5,4,2,0,2},
               new int[]{4,3,3,4,2,0}
            };
```

and I learned how to delete one specific column and row (for example 3). Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728523/how-to-delete-one-column-and-row-from-jagged-array-in-c-sharp).

Now I want to have dynamic programming as follows:
consider this array

```
     int[] day={1,4,5};
```

this array can be another array (**I used dynamic term for this reason**)

where the elements of array "day" shows the "dists1" matrix rows and columns, so I want the new jagged array named as " dists2" contains only columns and rows of 1,4,5  **with row and column "0" because it is fixed row and column** as follow:

```
  int[][] dists2 = new int[][]
            {
               new int[]{0,2,2,4},
               new int[]{2,0,5,3},
               new int[]{2,5,0,2},
               new int[]{4,3,2,0}
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply modify [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29728576/3956290) and replace the i != 2 condition with Contains method of the day array:

```
int[] day = {1,4,5};
int[][] finalDists = 
        dists.Where((arr, i) => i == 0 || day.Contains(i)) //skip rows
       .Select(arr=> arr.Where((item, i) => i == 0 || day.Contains(i)) //skip cols
       .ToArray())
       .ToArray();
```

Anyway if performance matters, it is way better to use for loops instead of LINQ.

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes it works fine for me :) just I think we must omit "!" before day, because I need those elements

Comment: You're welcome, yes, that's my mistake, I edit that.